# PySerial non blocking write?

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I'm using PySerial library for a project and it works fine. Though, now that my requirements have changed and i need to implement a non blocking serial write option. I went through PySerial official documentation as well as several examples however, couldn't find a suitable option. Now my question is : is non-blocking write possible with PySerial ? If yes, how ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out. To drain serial output physically, we have serial.drainOutput() function. It works but if you're looking for a real time operation it might not help as python is not a very good language if you're expecting a real time performance.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

From the [pySerial Documentation](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html):

> -timeout = None: wait forever
>
> -timeout = 0: non-blocking mode (return immediately on read)
>
> -timeout = x: set timeout to x seconds (float allowed)
>
> Writes are blocking by default, unless writeTimeout is set. For possible values refer to the list for timeout above

So I guess when you open your serial port you can set:

```
ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyXXX', writeTimeout = 0)
```

Comment: Well, I am not looking for write timeout. What I need is something like as follows. 1. Send data to serial for write. 2. do other tasks while data is being actually sent. (physically). 3. Once data is sent, it should notify me. The closest I came across to this is : serial.drainOutput() which actually waits for output data to be drained. However, it doesn't deliver real time performance. I wonder if there's this provision in pyserial.

Answer (score 0):

Try threading the send function.

```
    import _thread as thread
    def send_message(message, serial_interface)
        serial_interface.write(message)
        print("Done sending message!")

    serial_interface = serial.Serial('COM1')
    message = "hi"
    thread.start_new_thread(send_message, (message, serial_interface))
```